# Flask Middleware Access Response Data

Tags: python-3.x, flask, middleware, wsgi

I am trying to create a middleware in flask to store request and response inside database. I am able to access data present inside request but unable to figure out how to access data present inside response. Response header showing content-length 1000 & if i am changing it then showing differences in the content-length.

```
import pprint
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response

class LoggerMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, application):
        self.__application = application

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        errors = environ['wsgi.errors']
        length = int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', '0'))
        data = environ['wsgi.input'].read(min(4096, length))
        if data:
            print(data)

        pprint.pprint(('REQUEST', environ), stream=errors)

        def _start_response(status, headers, *args):
            pprint.pprint(('RESPONSE', status, headers), stream=errors)
            return start_response(status, headers, *args)

        return self.__application(environ, _start_response)
```